# What's the simplest way of returning the larger of two numbers?

Tags: c#, linq, collections, comparison, max

Let's say I have an entity that looks like this:

```
public class Album()
{
    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
    public List<Picture> Pictures { get; set; }
}
```

What I want to do is create a `LastActivity` property that will return the latest date of the activity. This is easy enough for the `Pictures` collection:

```
public DateTime LastActivity
{
    get { return Pictures.Max(x => x.LastUpdated); }
}
```

However, I also want to consider the `LastUpdated` property on the `Album` entity as well. I could use this code:

```
public DateTime LastActivity
{
    get { return Pictures.Max(x => x.LastUpdated) > this.LastUpdated
              ? Pictures.Max(x => x.LastUpdated)
              : this.LastUpdated) };
}
```

But this is bad because it will do the `Max()` transformation twice. Is there a better way of writing this code?

### Answer

This is the solution I came up with, based on the accepted answer:

```
public virtual DateTime LastActivity
{
    get
    {
        var max = Pictures.Any() ? Pictures.Max(x => x.LastUpdated) : DateTime.MinValue;
        return max > this.LastUpdated ? max : this.LastUpdated;
    }
}
```

The thing to watch out for is that if you do a `Max()` on an empty collection, you'll get an exception, so you have to check to see if there's anything in the collection first.

Comment: @mcl solution performs at about 35% faster then yours. But it's surprising that the compiler cannot optimize the above call. It actually creates separate delegate for each Pictures.Max call... weird. Sometimes it can optimize but sometimes it can't. In this particular case I wonder why it can't ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just store the max in a variable rather that performing the calculation twice.

```
public DateTime LastActivity
{
    get 
    { 
        var max = Pictures.Max(x => x.LastUpdated);
        return max > this.LastUpdated
          ? max
          : this.LastUpdated 
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping there'd be some .NET method to handle it, but sometimes the naive method is the best.

Answer (score 2):

Just assign the picture dates maximum to a local variable and then do the comparison you've already written.

Answer (score 1):

```
public DateTime LastActivity
{
    get
    {
        var picturesMax = Pictures.Max(x => x.LastUpdated);
        return picturesMax > this.LastUpdated
          ? picturesMax
          : this.LastUpdated)
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
public DateTime LastActivity 
{ 
    get 
    {
         DateTime lastPicture = Pictures.Max(x => x.LastUpdated);
         return lastPicture > this.LastUpdated ? lastPicture : this.LastUpdated;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public DateTime LastActivity
{         
    get { return Pictures.Select(x => x.LastUpdated).Concat(new DateTime[] { this.LastUpdated }).Max();
}
```

Comment: Using the newer C# notation you could change DateTime[] to [] to be more concise.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following in a framework library...

```
public static T Maximum<T>(params T[] values) 
    where T : struct, IComparable<T>
{
    var rV = values[0];
    foreach (var v in values.Where
        (v => v.CompareTo(rV) > 0))
        rV = v;
    return rV;
}
```

In client code I can simply write

`var maxVal = lib.Maximum(Value1, Value2,  .... , ValueN);`

Answer (score 0):

Just store the max value in a temporary:

```
public DateTime LastActivity
{
    get {
        DateTime maxLastUpdated = Pictures.Max(x => x.LastUpdated);
        return maxLastUpdated > this.LastUpdated
            ? maxLastUpdated
            : this.LastUpdated) };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep it LINQy...

```
public DateTime LastActivity
{
    get 
    { 
         return Pictures.Any(x => x.LastUpdated > this.LastUpdated) 
                ? Pictures.Max(x => x.LastUpdated) 
                : this.LastUpdated; 
    }
}
```

Update(s): added the default LastUpdated to be returned if the LINQ expression returns no results, and corrected for the OP's comment.

Comment: Unfortunately, `Max()` on an empty collection will throw an exception, not return null.

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly straightforward and should take an empty `Pictures` collection in its stride:

```
public DateTime LastActivity
{
    get
    {
        return Pictures.Aggregate(LastUpdated,
                            (a, x) => x.LastUpdated > a ? x.LastUpdated : a);
    }
}
```